# dropbox ios api - get thumbnails of all photos

Tags: objective-c, dropbox-api

I'm trying to implement my own dropbox photo chooser for iPhone, using dropBox SDK. I can't use the normal chooser because I have a different design. 
At the moment I'm succeeding only in receiving meta data for all images, but I can't get thumbnails at all. 
Is it a possible thing to do? thanks.

Comment: What did you try that didn't work? This is definitely possible, and there should be an obviously-named method to do it (something with the word "thumbnail" in it).

Comment: I can get a thumbnail of a specific item using thumbnail method in restClient. But I'm looking for a request that gives e all thumbnails of a list of items, using ios sdk.

Comment: You mean in a single HTTP request instead of one at a time? (Some sort of batch thumbnail retrieval?)

Comment: of course! It makes no sense to call it one a a time. there might be hundreds of them..  do you think it's possible?

Comment: No, Dropbox doesn't have a batch thumbnail API. You'll need to request each thumbnail individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THis is probaby way too late but the new sdk has thumbail batch downloads.
Search for "GetThumbnailBatch" in the code.